# How to make a for loop comparing one column of a dataframe to the rest of the columns of the dataframe?

Tags: r, for-loop

I've been trying to make a for loop that gives me a graph comparing an independent variable, called Status (type of gene mutated) to 64 other dependent variables. I want the for loop to create one graph per dependent variable, comparing Status to each dependant variable on my dataframe.

Status is the name of one column, and I want to compare Status (x axis) with the rest of the columns (y axis):

[image]

I have a for loop that I attempted to construct here, but whenever I open the pdf that it gives me all I get is a blank graph.

[image]

```
pdf("Leuk_Frac.pdf")

FORLOOP2 = for(i in 5:ncol(Leuk_Frac)){
  print(ggplot(Leuk_Frac, aes(x = unlist(Status), y = unlist(Leuk_Frac[,i]), fill = Status)))+
    geom_violin()+
    geom_boxplot()+
    xlab("Status")+
    ylab(colnames(Leuk_Frac[i]))+
    stat_cor(method = "pearson", label.x = 0, label.y = 0)
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

There are multiple things that go wrong - the y axis on the graphs come out as "Leuk_frac[i]" which is obviously not intended, how can I fix this?
The graphs are empty, there is no data on them, why is this?
This is my first time asking a question on here, what else could I have put?

Comment: The `print` parenthesis must close only at the end of the plot, like this you are printing without the `geom_*`'s, it only opens a plot with the axes sized according to variables, the violins and box-and-whiskers are plotted *later*.

Comment: Also remove the `FORLOOP2 = ` it does'nt do anything

Comment: I suggest you not try to iteratively (and with no delay) just plot all of them and hope that you see something. Other techniques include rendering multiple plots into (say) a multi-page PDF; adding `readline("next page")` so that the user (you) can say when to render the next column; or perhaps a big one, _facet_ them so that you have all (or at least many) of the other columns on one screen at a time: separate "canvas" but matching axes and legends and colors and such.

Comment: {ggpairs} might come in handy: https://ggobi.github.io/ggally/articles/ggpairs.html